# Solve $yp^2=2(z+xp+yq)$ using Charpit's method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want to solve $$yp^2=2(z+xp+yq)$$where, $$p=z_x,q=z_y$$
 
My attempt:

Let $f(x,y,z,p,q)=yp^2-2(z+xp+yq)$

So that $$f_x=-2p,f_y=p^2-2q,f_z=-2,f_p=2py-2x,f_q=-2y$$
As per Charpits method:$$\displaystyle \frac{dx}{f_p}=\frac{dy}{f_q}=\frac{dz}{pf_p+qf_q}=\frac{-dp}{f_x+pf_z}=\frac{-dq}{f_y+qf_z}$$
So,putting all the values and then equating second and fourth term,I get $p=c/{y^2}$ and equating fourth and fifth term gives $pq=p^3/12 +a$, where $a$ and $c $ are constants.

Then, $$dz=pdx +qdy \space \space \space .... (A)$$ 
Here I got stuck and I don't know how to solve(A) for $z$.

Please help me solve this problem.Any help towards this is much appreciated.

PS:I need "complete integral" of $yp^2=2(z+xp+yq)$,i.e  a solution of this form:$g(x,y,z,c_1,c_2)=0$,where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

You got $p=\frac{c}{y^2}$. Put this in the given equation and find the value of $q$. Then use  $\,dz=p\,dx+q\,dy $ and hence solve it.

Finally get , $$\,dz=\frac{c}{y^2}\,dx+\frac{c^2-2y^3z-2cxy}{2y^4}\,dy.$$
$$\implies2(y\,dz+z\,dy)=\frac{c^2}{y^3}\,dy+2c\frac{y\,dx-x\,dy}{y^2}$$
$$\implies 2\,d(zy)=\frac{c^2}{y^3}\,dy+2c\,d(x/y)$$
$$\implies2zy=-\frac{c^2}{2y^2}+2c.\frac{x}{y}+c_1$$

Comment: Great solution!Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

*On solving 4th and 5th term*
$\frac{-dp}{f_x+pf_z}$=$\frac{-dq}{f_y+qf_z}$
$\implies\frac{-dp}{-2p+p(-2)}=\frac{-dq}{p^2-2q+q(-2)}$
$\implies\frac{-dp}{-4p}=\frac{-dq}{p^2-4q}$\
$\implies(p^2-4q)(-dp)=(-4q)(-dq)$
$\implies(4q-p^2)(dp)=(4q)(dq)$
*ON integrating both side we get*
$\implies4pq-\frac{-p^3}{3}=4pq+c$ "where c is a constant"
$\implies(p^3)=c$